# for loop with 2 files consecutively and pass parameters to other script

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 files, one with `hostnames.txt` and one with `commands.txt` :

`hostnames.txt`:

```
switch1.txt
switch2.txt
switch3.txt
```

`commands.txt`:

```
show inter gi0/1
show inter gi0/0/1
show inter Eth1/1
```

I would like to execute `switch1` ( first switch ) with `show inter gi0/1` ( first command ) and then pick up `switch2` and execute with `show inter gi0/0/1` and so on until the file ends.

I'm using a TCL script to which I'm passing the parameters with hostname and command from a text files.

```
for  in `/bin/cat hostname.list`;
do
echo $n > oneswitch.txt

for  in `/bin/cat interfinal.list`;
do
echo $m > onecommand.txt

for switch in `/bin/cat oneswitch.txt
tclscript -u username -p password -t $switch -r onecommand.txt .
```

And I couldn't achieve it, how and what are the possible loops I can use and what login can I put in place to get this achieved?

What happens with the above one is that I can only execute with last switch with last command.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paste` -> try this at a bash prompt: `paste -d ":" hostname.list interfinal.list`

So:

```
paste -d ":" hostname.list interfinal.list | while IFS=: read -r switch cmd; do
    tclscript -u username -p password -t "$switch" -r "$cmd" .
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {1..3}; do                                                      
    eval $(paste -d' ' <(sed -n ${i}p commands.txt) <(sed -n ${i}p hostnames.txt))
done
```

This script will execute the commands:

```
show inter gi0/1 switch1.txt
show inter gi0/0/1 switch2.txt
show inter Eth1/1 switch3.txt
```